Interactive plotting %matplotlib notebook in Google Colabs
It is June 2024 and I would like to know whether Google Colab supports interactive plotting using matplotlib? I ran !pip install PyQt5 and I get the following error when I run %matplotlib notebook in a Colab cell:

ImportError: Cannot load backend 'Qt5Agg' which requires the 'qt'
interactive framework, as 'headless' is currently running

There are many posts on SO describing problems enabling interactive plotting with matplotlib in Notebooks in general and I found this post below from 4 years ago stating that Google Colabs does not support interactive plotting using the matplotlib library.
generate-interactive-plot-using-mne-package-in-google-colab
Also here is another post from 5+ years ago and the accepted answer is a solution using plotly not matplotlib.
interactive-matplotlib-figures-in-google-colab
Since these posts were 4-5 years ago I am wondering if there is an updated official status of interactive plotting using matplotlib in Google Colab?

!pip install ipympl  ; from google.colab import output ; output.enable_custom_widget_manager() ; %matplotlib widget
